# Unable to install Windows 10 on Surface Book 2?

Tags: windows-10, boot, microsoft-surface, bcd

I'm trying to install Windows 10 on a Surface Book 2, but Windows keeps giving the error "Windows could not update the computer's boot configuration. Installation cannot proceed."

I have tried completely deleting all the partitions and completely cleaning the drive using the 'clean' diskpart command, but the problem still persists every time I try to install Windows. Currently, I have 4 partitions as shown in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYpV1.jpg), which the Windows installer created. Oddly, diskpart shows that the SSD has 0 bytes free after it fails installing Windows.

Also, I am unable to run 'bootrec /FixBoot' unless I run 'bootsect/nt60 sys' each time. Also "bcdedit" commands do not work and give me the error "The boot configuration data store could not be opened. The volume for a file has been externally altered so that the opened file is no longer valid."

I'm not sure why this problem could be occurring. Can this possibly be a hardware issue?

Comment: Updated. There are 4 partitions, which Windows created during the installation, but they are otherwise empty and I can delete any of them

Comment: I did. Those were the partitions that it created.

Comment: I apologize; Huge block of text; Missed that statement.

Comment: I have tried that as I have mentioned in my question, but unfortunately it does not work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101864/discussion-between-notorious-and-ramhound).

Comment: Did you download the install ISO via the [Windows Media Creator](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10)? Is Secure Boot enabled?  Just an FYI, `convert gpt` should be issued in `diskpart` after issuing `clean`.  AFAIK, Windows 10 does not allow manual configuration of the EFI boot files, which is why `bootrec /fixboot` won't work _(I've yet to find anything on Microsoft Docs that addresses manually modifying the EFI boot files on Win 10, which is what `/fixboot` does - it rebuilds the boot directory from a known good copy kept within `%WinDir%` when using a non-UEFI MB)_